# android video calling

Tags: android

in android for voice call we use below code

```
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:+436641234567"));
                startActivityForResult(intent,0);
```

then what is the intent or code for Video call

Answer (score 0):

Video calling is easily possible if both the users have a 3G connection. I did a sample code where on a button click the call is initiated to a number. I wrote the following code inside the onclick listener:

```
   Intent callIntent = new Intent("com.android.phone.videocall");
        callIntent.putExtra("videocall", true);
        callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phonenumber));
        startActivity(callIntent);
```

Comment: I am getting android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.android.phone.videocall dat=tel:xxxxxxxxxx (has extras) }. can you please help me. Thank you in Advance